# Created a small form class with 3 radiobuttons, whenever I load the form from the main program, one of them is checked, why?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

In my code i have all the radiobuttons.checked = false;

```
        this.Opener3 = opener3;
        InitializeComponent();


        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
```

There's not even one line, where i set any of those buttons check to true, in the whole code! What is happening? Is there some hidden code that's doing this? I smell noob stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you added a `RadioButton` first, then copy/pasted it twice. So the last one that was added has a `TabOrder` of 0, and now it's the selected control when you display your Form.

One way to change this is to include the following lines of code in your constructor.

```
radioButton1.TabIndex = 1;
radioButton2.TabIndex = 2;
radioButton3.TabIndex = 3;

button1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Better yet, fix the tab order at design time, so the control you specify gets focus. The easiest way to do this (especially when you have a lot of controls on your Form), is to select the "Tab Order" menu item from "View" menu:

[image]

And then select each control on your Form in the order you want them to be in.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I've no idea that this "thing" existed.. I'll research about it, thanks

Comment: Damn!, It only worked the first time I used it, now the program is placing back Zone C as checked, even bruteforcing it on the load with a radiobutton.Checked =false; won't uncheck the radio button

Comment: It's funny because on one of the forms, it's working correctly, it doesn't place any button checked, on the other ones ( a copy of the first) it always checks a radiobutton, and I have no idea why, the tabs index are similar in all of them, and the autocheck is true in all of them (including the correct one), if I disable autocheck, it doesnt check when the user clicks on it.

Comment: I solved it, It had to do with how a opener was placed to interact with the main form, I'm not really sure why because someone helped me getting that along, but it's fixed now.